# In Linux 'top' command, is there any way to keep track of values?

Tags: shell-script, monitoring, top

I'm using the Linux "top" command to monitor %CPU of particular process. As the values keep on changing every few seconds, is there any way to keep track of values in a separate file or as a graphical representation? Is it possible to do it using any shell scripts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to this question can range from a simple command, to complex monitoring tools, depending on your needs.

You can start by simply running `top -b -n 1 >> file.txt` (-b for batch mode, -n 1 for running a single iteration of top) and store the output (appended) in the file.txt. You can filter also "top" output like `top -b -n 1 | grep init` to see only the data for the "init" process or `top -b -n 1 | grep "init" | head -1 |awk '{print $9}'` to get the 9th column of the init process data (the CPU value).

If you want to use in a shell script, you could:

```
CPU=$(top -b -n1 | grep "myprocess" | head -1 | awk '{print $9}')
MEM=$(top -b -n1 | grep "myprocess" | head -1 | awk '{print $10}')
```

Or, with a single execution of top:

```
read CPU MEM <<<$(top -b -n1 | grep "myprocess" | head -1 | awk '{print $9 " " $10}')
```

(note that grep, head and awk could be merged in a single awk command but for the shake of simplicity I'm using separate commands).

We used top in this example but there are alternate methods for other metrics (check `sar`, `iostat`, `vmstat`, `iotop`, `ftop`, and even reading /proc/*).

Now you have a way to access the data (CPU usage). And in our example we are appending it to a text file. But you can use other tools to store the data and even graph them: store in csv and graph with gnuplot/python/openoffice, use monitoring&graping tools like zabbix, rrdtools, cacti, etc. There is a big world of monitoring tools that allow to collect and graph the data like CPU usage, memory usage, disk io, and even custom metrics (number of mysql connections, etc).

EDIT: finally, to specifically answering your question, if you want to keep track of changes easily for a simple test, you can run `top -b -n 1 >> /tmp/file.txt` in your /etc/crontab file, by running top every 5 minutes (or any other time interval if you replace the /5 below).

```
0-59/5 * * * * root top -b -n1 >>/tmp/output.txt
```

(and a grep + head -1 in the command above if you're only intestered in a single process data).

Note that the output.txt will grow, so if you want to reset it daily or weekly, you can "rm" it with another crontab entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ps -o pid,pcpu $(pgrep particular-process) >> file`. Run it at a regular interval.

Comment: Except this will only probe the values so your results won't be as accurate as if you use top which computes averages (even though it updates every few seconds).