# Track CPU load of a process

Tags: terminal, top

I have a process `foo` that I would like to run from the Terminal. At the same time, I'm interested in identifying how much this process is consuming the CPU, and so I want, for example, to go into `top`, find the process `foo` (only one process will have this name), get the value from the `%CPU` column, and append that value to a file with the datetime timestamp and the extracted value on one row. With these values, I can produce a plot and some descriptive statistics to understand the workload of `foo` better.

Moreover, I'd like this CPU load extraction to continue every `n` seconds (for example every `n=1` second), and I would like it to start when `foo` starts and end when `foo` has completed processing.

As far as I understand, this requires that two processes simultaneously.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this? Preferably as a direct command to provide the Terminal—with a shell script as a last resort if necessary.

**EDIT**: the link in the comment below answers how to retrieve values from `top`. However, I still need to identify how to run two processes simulateously—one "main" process and one tracking process, with the tracking process starting and ending when the main process starts and ends, respectively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Linux 'top' command, is there any way to keep track of values?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199315/in-linux-top-command-is-there-any-way-to-keep-track-of-values)

Comment: @MarcusMüller not fully—it answers how to get values from `top`. However, it does not help me in solving how to run this "tracking" process next to the process that is tracked, with the tracking process starting and ending when the main process starts and ends, respectively.

Comment: starting: ideally, whatever starts the main process starts your supervisor along; if the main process is a service, which I'd expect here, then systemd (or whatever supervises services) can automate that for you. Ending: well when the observed process can no longer be found, it's dead, you can exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the main bit of this is answered in the comments via a link to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199315/in-linux-top-command-is-there-any-way-to-keep-track-of-valueshttps://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199315/in-linux-top-command-is-there-any-way-to-keep-track-of-values)

I'll attempt to answer the remainder of your question.

Since I do not know how you're running the 'main' process, I will cover this both in a wrapper script context, and in a systemd context

However before that I want to address a misconception;

You can't truly run these processes *simultaneously*, you should expect to either wait for the main process to start (If you start your watcher before) or start your watcher after, which will allow the watcher to assume the main process is already running.

**systemd**:

If your process is managed by systemd, you will most likely have a service file for that unit.

These files are typically stored in `/etc/systemd/system/` or `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` depending on your distribution.

The easiest way to manipulate these files is to use the following syntax

```
systemctl edit <service name> --full
```

Specifying `--full` will allow you to modify a copy of the original file; rather than making drop-in edits(editing blind essentially) which is useful if you are not familiar with this particular service.

The actual modifications you need to make are to add an `ExecStartPre=` or `ExecStartPost=` and an `ExecStopPost=`

`ExecStartPre` will do the specified action (run your watcher script/program) **before** the service is started

`ExecStartPost` will do the specified action (run your watcher script/program) **after** the service is started **only if it starts successfully**

Similarly, `ExecStopPost` will do its specified action **after** the service has exited(completed the action defined in `ExecStop`).

The following is an example of this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo

[Service]
# Start the watcher
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/foo-watcher
# Actual service start
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/foo-daemon start
# Actual service stop
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/foo-daemon stop
# Stop the watcher
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/pkill foo-watcher

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For your `ExecStopPost` is may be more advisable to kill your process via PID rather than name, however there are plenty of examples of products that don't do this; so be aware of the risk of unintentionally killing an identically named process.

[Additional Information on service file directives](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=)

**The startup script method**:

Basically you will want to wrap your process in a start-up bash script,
since you want to manage multiple processes with this script, it would be useful to background the watcher and the main process.

If you intend to make this a fully-functional management script, you will also need to track the pids of these backgrounded processes.

Here's a simple example of that being done:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Do we have too many arguments(Or too few)? Exit if so.
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
        exit 1
fi

if [ "$1" == "start" ]
then
        # Start the watcher as a job and save the pid to a variable
        /usr/bin/foo-watcher &
        wPid="$!"
        
        # Start the main process as a job and save the pid to a variable
        /usr/bin/foo-daemon &
        mPid="$!"
        
        # Save the PIDs to a file, make sure than the main process
        # (foo-daemon) doesn't already do this for us
        /usr/bin/echo "$wPid" > /var/run/foo-watcher.pid
        /usr/bin/echo "$mPid" > /var/run/foo-daemon.pid
elif [ "$1" == "stop" ]
then
        # Grab PID from files and store in a variable, since kill
        # doesn't read from stdin
        wPid="$(/usr/bin/cat /var/run/foo-watcher.pid)"
        mPid="$(/usr/bin/cat /var/run/foo-daemon.pid)"
        
        # Kill the processes
        /usr/bin/kill "$wPid"
        /usr/bin/kill "$mPid"
        
        # Delete pid files
        /usr/bin/rm -f /var/run/foo-watcher.pid
        /usr/bin/rm -f /var/run/foo-daemon.pid
else 
        # We didn't get a valid input, exit (maybe display help?)
        exit 1
fi
```

In the event that you are not in control of the main process exiting (in the case of `dd` or `rm` or similar processes which do a thing and exit). The following is a modification to the above script that would handle this case.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Start the watcher as a job and save the pid to a variable
/usr/bin/foo-watcher &
wPid="$!"

# Start the main process as a job and save the pid to a variable
/usr/bin/foo-daemon &
mPid="$!"

while true
do
        #Check ps for the process via PID
        status="$(ps -q "$mPid" | wc -l)"
        #Did ps return anything, if not, kill the watcher
        if [ "$status" -eq 1 ]
        then
                kill "$wPid"
                exit 0
        fi
        #Interval to check if process is running in seconds
        sleep 1 
done
```

Comment: kudos for a thorough answer—thank you!